# Style app with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of blocks that are drawn inside an ng-repeat.
I use the BootStrap grid to set the width of each block.
I want to expand a block when clicked. By default, the blocks are drawn using col-lg-2. The idea would be to use col-lg-12 after the click event (ng-click).

Would anyone know how I apply this style to each block individually using the ng-class or ng-style directives?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy using a combination of `ng-click` and `ng-class` built-in directives:

```
<my-block ng-class="{'col-lg-12': item.clicked, 'col-lg-2': !item.clicked}" 
  ng-click="clickMe(item)"></my-block>
```

Then in your controller, you would make a scope function:

```
$scope.clickMe = function(item) {
  item.clicked = !item.clicked;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an object array. Then you can add additional property into your objects call it className in array. Set it by default col-lg-2. In ng-click function you can change the property value to col-lg-12 which will affect individually. You need to use this property with ng-class in order to change the class.

Comment: It worked very well here. Thanks for the tip friend.